# Mysql command line doesnt accept correct password

Tags: mysql

I download and install mysql and all fine and i put a password.The thing is that for the first time it accepts the correct password on the mysql command line but after a restart i cant login with anything. Any sort of help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to ask good questions. You haven't added any information of what you have done and what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question to include the information, what you have installed MySQL, how you have changed the configuration, how you tried the login, how you start the MySQL server after a restart, what the content of the server configuration file is, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the graphical interface to set the password? I advise you to do everything from the command line, because often there are problems with lower/upper case ...
The syntax is:
SET PASSWORD = 'auth_string';